# How to grep IP addresses from mashup data text file in linux

Tags: grep

For example:

```
216.93.125.232  Default Virtual Host    97070789      
Virtual Host 216.93.125.232  Default     9705329 
Default     9705329
9705329 Default Virtual Host Virtual Host 216.93.125.232
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" file.txt
```

Results:

```
216.93.125.232
216.93.125.232
216.93.125.232
```